# How to upload files to site without ftp?

Tags: web-services

My company uses a customer management system that is sort of terrible.  We have to upload tons of files to it but it has no ftp server for us to use and only allows one file upload at a time through it's uploader.  Is there anyway to write a program to automate something like this?  Thanks.

Comment: **Maybe**. Come back when you've done some research and have a specific question.

Comment: Please forgive the bluntness of my fellow StackOverflow user's comment above. However he or she is correct in their sentiment, which is this website is not the correct forum for open-ended questions such as this.